# Dynamically adding columns to DataTable

Tags: javascript, jquery, dynamic, datatables

I'm having trouble getting data to display correctly. I have a datatable that I want to display results this way:

Year | Source #1 opps | Source #1 bids | Source #1 sales | Source #1 total | ...continuing this way depending on how many sources they selected.

so the year will be fixed but it will need to add columns based on how many sources are selected. Each row will be a year. Right now I can only get the row to display if I have  hard coded. It will change the name of the header but won't create a new one. Here is my code:

The display results section:

```
      if (result != null && result.status) {
          if (sourceValues.length === 0) {
              return
          }
      console.log(result.models)
      var sourceNamesSet = new Set();
          var sourceNames = Array.from(sourceNamesSet);

          marketingReport.drawTable(result, sourceNames)
      result.models.forEach(function (entry) {
          entry.Items.forEach(function (item) {
              if (!item.IsGrandTotal) {
                  if (!sourceNamesSet.has(item.SourceName)) {
                      sourceNamesSet.add(item.SourceName);
                  }
              }
          });
      });
             

          var rowsData = [];
          $.each(result.models, function (index, model) {
              if (model.Items && model.Items.length > 1) {
                  var total = model.Items[1].Opps + model.Items[1].Bids + model.Items[1].Sales;
                  var rowData = [
                      model.Items[1].Opps,
                      model.Items[1].Bids,
                      model.Items[1].Sales,
                      total,
                  ];
                  rowsData.push(rowData);
   
              } else {
                  console.error("Model doesn't have the expected structure or Items are missing.");
              }
          });

          var table = $('#marketing-report-grid-new');
          table.DataTable().rows.add(rowsData).draw();
      } else {
```

and the draw table function:

```
drawTable: function (data, sourceValues) {
       console.log(data);
       console.log(sourceValues)

       var table = $('#marketing-report-grid-new');
       var thead = table.find('thead');

       thead.empty();

       var headerRow = $('<tr>');

       headerRow.append($('<th>').text('Year'));

       sourceValues.forEach(function (source) {
           headerRow.append($('<th>').text(`${source} Opps`));
           headerRow.append($('<th>').text(`${source} Bids`));
           headerRow.append($('<th>').text(`${source} Sales`));
           headerRow.append($('<th>').text(`${source} Total`));
       });

       thead.append(headerRow);
       headerRow.append($('<th>').text('Grand Total'));

       table.DataTable({
           autoWidth: true,
       });
   },
```

Here is what the result.models looks like:

```
[
    {
        "Orders": 1,
        "Title": "2017",
        "Items": [
            {
                "IsGrandTotal": true,
                "SourceName": "GRAND TOTAL",
                "Opps": 34,
                "Bids": 19,
                "Sales": 4
            },
            {
                "IsGrandTotal": false,
                "SourceName": "E-mail - General",
                "Opps": 34,
                "Bids": 19,
                "Sales": 4
            },
            {
                "IsGrandTotal": false,
                "SourceName": "Google",
                "Opps": 0,
                "Bids": 0,
                "Sales": 0
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "Orders": 2,
        "Title": "2018",
        "Items": [
            {
                "IsGrandTotal": true,
                "SourceName": "GRAND TOTAL",
                "Opps": 109,
                "Bids": 65,
                "Sales": 20
            },
            {
                "IsGrandTotal": false,
                "SourceName": "E-mail - General",
                "Opps": 99,
                "Bids": 62,
                "Sales": 17
            },
            {
                "IsGrandTotal": false,
                "SourceName": "Google",
                "Opps": 10,
                "Bids": 3,
                "Sales": 3
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "Orders": 3,
        "Title": "2019",
        "Items": [
            {
                "IsGrandTotal": true,
                "SourceName": "GRAND TOTAL",
                "Opps": 138,
                "Bids": 64,
                "Sales": 7
            },
            {
                "IsGrandTotal": false,
                "SourceName": "E-mail - General",
                "Opps": 39,
                "Bids": 29,
                "Sales": 5
            },
            {
                "IsGrandTotal": false,
                "SourceName": "Google",
                "Opps": 99,
                "Bids": 35,
                "Sales": 2
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "Orders": 4,
        "Title": "2020",
        "Items": [
            {
                "IsGrandTotal": true,
                "SourceName": "GRAND TOTAL",
                "Opps": 128,
                "Bids": 75,
                "Sales": 16
            },
            {
                "IsGrandTotal": false,
                "SourceName": "E-mail - General",
                "Opps": 26,
                "Bids": 14,
                "Sales": 8
            },
            {
                "IsGrandTotal": false,
                "SourceName": "Google",
                "Opps": 102,
                "Bids": 61,
                "Sales": 8
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "Orders": 5,
        "Title": "2021",
        "Items": [
            {
                "IsGrandTotal": true,
                "SourceName": "GRAND TOTAL",
                "Opps": 226,
                "Bids": 112,
                "Sales": 28
            },
            {
                "IsGrandTotal": false,
                "SourceName": "E-mail - General",
                "Opps": 71,
                "Bids": 46,
                "Sales": 5
            },
            {
                "IsGrandTotal": false,
                "SourceName": "Google",
                "Opps": 155,
                "Bids": 66,
                "Sales": 23
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "Orders": 6,
        "Title": "2022",
        "Items": [
            {
                "IsGrandTotal": true,
                "SourceName": "GRAND TOTAL",
                "Opps": 274,
                "Bids": 154,
                "Sales": 45
            },
            {
                "IsGrandTotal": false,
                "SourceName": "E-mail - General",
                "Opps": 223,
                "Bids": 126,
                "Sales": 37
            },
            {
                "IsGrandTotal": false,
                "SourceName": "Google",
                "Opps": 51,
                "Bids": 28,
                "Sales": 8
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "Orders": 7,
        "Title": "2023",
        "Items": [
            {
                "IsGrandTotal": true,
                "SourceName": "GRAND TOTAL",
                "Opps": 101,
                "Bids": 62,
                "Sales": 27
            },
            {
                "IsGrandTotal": false,
                "SourceName": "E-mail - General",
                "Opps": 46,
                "Bids": 32,
                "Sales": 19
            },
            {
                "IsGrandTotal": false,
                "SourceName": "Google",
                "Opps": 55,
                "Bids": 30,
                "Sales": 8
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "Orders": 8,
        "Title": "2024",
        "Items": [
            {
                "IsGrandTotal": true,
                "SourceName": "GRAND TOTAL",
                "Opps": 0,
                "Bids": 0,
                "Sales": 0
            },
            {
                "IsGrandTotal": false,
                "SourceName": "E-mail - General",
                "Opps": 0,
                "Bids": 0,
                "Sales": 0
            },
            {
                "IsGrandTotal": false,
                "SourceName": "Google",
                "Opps": 0,
                "Bids": 0,
                "Sales": 0
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Comment: This probably isn't the right answer, but why not approach it like this: User adds a year, you update your data source to accomodate, delete the old table and redraw a new one based on the updated data source?

Comment: It is possible that no one will attempt to answer this question due to its complexity. Please create a simplified demo (either on jsFiddle or as a StackSnippet - edit your answer and press Ctrl + M) that readers can experiment with to solve your dilemma.